# Git way of handling floating branch like in StarTeam

Tags: git, git-branch

In my project I have a folder that contains a lot of data that needs to be versioned. Most of the time I don't need it, so I just do:

```
$ git clone myrepo
$ cd myrepo
```

Sometimes I also need the latest stuff from my data branch, that is in it's own folder

`$ git checkout databranch -- datadir`

When I checkout data branch, I just need the latest stuff. Data branch should not contain any versioning of anything but its own content and master branch should not contain data branch stuff by default.

This sounds like git-submodule, but I must keep everything contained in a single repository. And I'd like to keep my data-branch, when selected, floating on top of master like StarTeam is able to do (if I recall correctly).

Is this possible in Git? What kind of workflow would you suggest as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout databranch -- datadir
git rm -r --cached datadir
```

and you're done.